# Expand and useArrows are not working for Treepanel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am using the below code of `treepanel` in my project but expnad is not happening.`useArrow` is also not working. But when I run same code in fidller every thing is working as expected. Can anyone help me to figure it out what am I missing.

Expand is not happening. All the value including child item displaying. Here is my code.

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    useArrows: true,
    autoScroll: false,
    animate: true,
    enableDD: false,
    title: 'Configuration',
    width: 200,
    height: 400,
    rootVisible: false,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "Configure Application",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage Application",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "Scenario",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "User Configuration",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage User",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User rights",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Test Configuration",
                //leaf: true,
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    text: "Manage User",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User rights",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }
    }),
    listeners: {
        itemclick: function(s, r) {
            alert(r.data.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is console output when you click on any node?

Comment: Now my code is getting expand. But arrow and folder is still not coming. Do I add need to add extra css ?

Comment: Are images in correct directory relative to `CSS` file?

Comment: But I am not using any css. I mean I am using `useArrows: true,` config.

Comment: How about `ExtJS` default `CSS`?

Comment: Well I am not sure about this. let me check. because as i see dafult css is loading. well  let me check